# Wrong source file when debugging with Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

My project include RecyclerView as dependency with gradle.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

I want to debug a function in RecyclerView. When I jump to the function use "Ctrl-B" the source file is:

```
...\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7\21.0.3\recyclerview-v7-21.0.3-sources.jar!\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView.java
```

And I toggle a breakpoint in it, line 200 for example.
But when I attached the debugger and ran my app, the debugger stopped at line 200 of another file:

```
...\android-sdk\sources\android-21\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView.java
```

It's the source code from android sdk which is a different version from support lib jar.

How can I make the debugger to use source file from recyclerview-v7-21.0.3-sources.jar?

Comment: I have the same issue with the latest update to AS. Have you found a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. The debugger would step into the non-support version of the file. I just removed the `android-21` source files using the android sdk manager. Then when I debugged it again it used the correct support version of the file.

Now that I'm done with it I've re-installed the `android-21` source files.

Comment: How exactly do you "remove source files" of a specific version with the sdk manager?
Thanks..

Comment: uhhh, it's been a while now... but if I recall you can select the package in the Android SDK Manager and then click "Delete packages"